# partial specialization of a method with variadic templated template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a code, which compiles successfully (g++ 4.9.2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// general function for any variadic templated argument
template<template<typename ...> class T, typename ...TTs>
void
foo(T<TTs...>& arg)
{
    std::cout << "T<TTs...>" << std::endl;
}

template<typename ...Ts>
struct xxx
{
    // not important
};

// specialization for only variadic templated xxx
template<typename ...TTs> void
foo(xxx<TTs...>& arg)
{
    std::cout << "xxx<TTs...>" << std::endl;
}

// specialization for non-variadic templated xxx
template<typename TT> void
foo(xxx<TT>& arg)
{
    std::cout << "xxx<TT>" << std::endl;
}

// specialization for xxx<uint8_t>
template<> void
foo(xxx<uint8_t>& arg)
{
    std::cout << "xxx<uint8_t>" << std::endl;
}

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    xxx<uint8_t> x1;
    std::cout << "xxx<uint8_t> => ";
    foo(x1);

    xxx<uint16_t> x2;
    std::cout << "xxx<uint16_t> => ";
    foo(x2);

    xxx<uint8_t,uint16_t> x3;
    std::cout << "xxx<uint8_t,uint16_t> => ";
    foo(x3);

    std::pair<uint8_t,uint16_t> x4;
    std::cout << "std::pair<uint8_t,uint16_t> => ";
    foo(x4);

    return 0;
}
```

and produces:

```
xxx<uint8_t> => xxx<uint8_t>
xxx<uint16_t> => xxx<TT>
xxx<uint8_t,uint16_t> => xxx<TTs...>
std::pair<uint8_t,uint16_t> => T<TTs...>
```

Now I want to have these foo methods inside a class, and write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class abc
{
public:
    // general function for any variadic templated argument
    template<template<typename ...> class T, typename ...TTs>
    void
    foo(T<TTs...>& arg)
    {
        std::cout << "T<TTs...>" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename ...Ts>
struct xxx
{
    // not important
};

// specialization for only variadic templated xxx
template<typename ...TTs> void
abc::foo(xxx<TTs...>& arg)
{
    std::cout << "xxx<TTs...>" << std::endl;
}

// specialization for non-variadic templated xxx
template<typename TT> void
abc::foo(xxx<TT>& arg)
{
    std::cout << "xxx<TT>" << std::endl;
}

// specialization for xxx<uint8_t>
template<> void
abc::foo(xxx<uint8_t>& arg)
{
    std::cout << "xxx<uint8_t>" << std::endl;
}

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    abc p;

    xxx<uint8_t> x1;
    std::cout << "xxx<uint8_t> => ";
    p.foo(x1);

    xxx<uint16_t> x2;
    std::cout << "xxx<uint16_t> => ";
    p.foo(x2);

    xxx<uint8_t,uint16_t> x3;
    std::cout << "xxx<uint8_t,uint16_t> => ";
    p.foo(x3);

    std::pair<uint8_t,uint16_t> x4;
    std::cout << "std::pair<uint8_t,uint16_t> => ";
    p.foo(x4);

    return 0;
}
```

and this produces a compilation error:

```
test_ko.cc:24:1: error: prototype for ‘void abc::foo(xxx<TTs ...>&)’ does not match any in class ‘abc’
 abc::foo(xxx<TTs...>& arg)
 ^
test_ko.cc:10:5: error: candidate is: template<template<class ...> class T, class ... TTs> void abc::foo(T<TTs ...>&)
     foo(T<TTs...>& arg)
     ^
test_ko.cc:31:1: error: prototype for ‘void abc::foo(xxx<TT>&)’ does not match any in class ‘abc’
 abc::foo(xxx<TT>& arg)
 ^
test_ko.cc:10:5: error: candidate is: template<template<class ...> class T, class ... TTs> void abc::foo(T<TTs ...>&)
     foo(T<TTs...>& arg)
```

I want a specialization for foo methods, not declaring a new signature inside abc class (because there is a class with templates, a part of a library, and separate specialization, for later declared xxx class).

It looks for me that code with methods is similar to one with functions, but I get error here. What I do wrong?

Comment: It is not possible to partially specialize a function template.  There is no such thing.  You can *overload* a function template, and *fully specialize* it, but if you think you are partially specializing you are in error.  Generally if you got rid of your full specialization you'd be in better shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// general function for any variadic templated argument
template<template<typename ...> class T, typename ...TTs>
void
foo(T<TTs...>& arg)
{
  std::cout << "T<TTs...>" << std::endl;
}
```

This is a template function.

```
template<typename ...Ts>
struct xxx
{
  // not important
};

// specialization for only variadic templated xxx
template<typename ...TTs> void
foo(xxx<TTs...>& arg)
{
  std::cout << "xxx<TTs...>" << std::endl;
}
```

This is *not* a specialization.  This is a different template function whose name `foo` overloads with the above template function.

```
// specialization for non-variadic templated xxx
template<typename TT> void
foo(xxx<TT>& arg)
{
  std::cout << "xxx<TT>" << std::endl;
}
```

This is *not* a specialization.  This is a different template function whose name `foo` overloads with the above template functions.

```
// specialization for xxx<uint8_t>
template<> void
foo(xxx<uint8_t>& arg)
{
  std::cout << "xxx<uint8_t>" << std::endl;
}
```

This is a full specialization of one of the above template functions.  I think the 3rd one, but I wouldn't bet money on it.  (I believe it specializes whichever template `xxx<uint8_t>&` would be dispatched to if you called `foo`).

Instead of this full specialization, I would instead write:

```
inline foo(xxx<uint8_t>& arg)
{
  std::cout << "xxx<uint8_t>" << std::endl;
}
```

which is a brand new overload of `foo` again.  Overloads are far less quirky than full function specializations.

**There is no such thing as partial template function specialization**.

This explains why your attempt to specialize methods with the same syntax doesn't work.  **There is no such thing as partial template member function specialization** either.

You either have to write the overloads in the class itself, or dispatch to a different context.

What "went wrong" and was the proximate cause of the error is that your initial code introduced *new overloads*.  You are not permitted to introduce new overloads of a method outside of the class definition, so the compiler pointed out your error.

---

Here is a useful technique.  We are in `abc`:

```
// general function for any variadic templated argument
  template<template<typename ...> class T, typename ...TTs>
  void foo(T<TTs...>& arg)
  {
    return foo(*this, arg);
  }
private:
  template<template<typename ...> class T, typename ...TTs>
  friend void foo(abc& self, T<TTs...>& arg)
  {
    std::cout << "T<TTs...>" << std::endl;
  }
```

Our `foo` method extends to a `foo` friend.

We then add code in the same namespace as `abc`:

```
template<typename ...TTs> void
foo(abc& self, xxx<TTs...>& arg)
{
  std::cout << "xxx<TTs...>" << std::endl;
}

template<typename TT> void
foo(abc& self, xxx<TT>& arg)
{
  std::cout << "xxx<TT>" << std::endl;
}

inline void foo(abc& self, xxx<uint8_t>& arg)
{
  std::cout << "xxx<uint8_t>" << std::endl;
}
```

and they are found via ADL when `abc::foo` is called.